# An android ioc container similar to C# Castle Windsor

Tags: android, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I am looking for an android ioc container that resembles [Castle Windsor](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/basic-tutorial.md). There is Google Guice for Java. And Roboguice for android is now retired.
Can someone please give me suggestions.

I have so far looked at Dagger 2

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon I asked it as a problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175416/how-do-i-inject-an-abstraction-using-an-ioc-container-like-dagger-2) but no one answered it.

Comment: @NewbieCoder I answered your question you are referencing

Comment: @DavidRawson thank you so much!!! :)